# wpf ObjectDataProvider method parameter bind to combobox selected value

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid, objectdataprovider

I'm dealing with a problem in WPF binding.
I'm creating a user control which present a datagrid, fiiltered by 2 possible values.
The first value is set by a textbox, the second one by a combo box.
I'm using an ObjectDataProvider to map a methos with 2 parameters, and the textbox and the combobox should set these 2 parameters.
Here's the code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="VisualHorse.Corse"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VisualHorse"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="530" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="HorseDataProvider"
             ObjectType="{x:Type local:HorseDataProvider}"
             MethodName="GetCorse" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Static Member="system:String.Empty" />
            <x:Static Member="system:String.Empty" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel >
    <Grid  Name="GRIDFilter" Height="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Data corsa" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Content="Località" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Content="N° Corsa" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Content="Filtra" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="50" Height="30" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="DPDataCorsa" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="115" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="CBlocalita" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" >
            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource HorseDataProvider}"
                 Path="MethodParameters[0]"
                 BindsDirectlyToSource="true"/>
            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Name="TBNumCorsa" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0" >
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource HorseDataProvider}"
                 Path="MethodParameters[1]"
                 BindsDirectlyToSource="true"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>

    <DataGrid Name="DGCorse" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HorseDataProvider}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,10,0,0" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Localita.descrizione}" Header="Località" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=data, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" Header="Data Corsa" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=numero}" Header="N° Corsa" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TipoCorsa.descrizione}" Header="Tipo corsa" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TipoTerreno.descrizione}" Header="Terreno" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TipoFantino.descrizione}" Header="Tipo fantino" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=premio, StringFormat=\{0:c\}}" Header="Premio" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=distacchi}" Header="Distacchi" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=distanza}" Header="Distanza" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TipoPista.descrizione}" Header="Pista" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Eta.descrizione}" Header="Età" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

What's wrong with it?
Everything works fine if I just bind the textbox property, but trying to bind the Combobox.SeletedValue property to the first method parameter it throws an exception (silently handled by the wpf engine):

> System.Windows.Data Error: 35 :
>   ObjectDataProvider: Failure trying to
>   invoke method on type;
>   Method='GetCorse';
>   Type='HorseDataProvider'; Error='No
>   method was found with matching
>   parameter signature.'
>   MissingMethodException:'System.MissingMethodException:
>   Method
>   'VisualHorse.HorseDataProvider.GetCorse'
>   not found.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String
>   name, BindingFlags bindingFlags,
>   Binder binder, Object target, Object[]
>   providedArgs, ParameterModifier[]
>   modifiers, CultureInfo culture,
>   String[] namedParams)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider.InvokeMethodOnInstance(Exception&
>   e)'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be much easier if to use MVVM.

Comment: I'm new to WPF and I'd like to understand and experiment the XAML features with a direct approach, before diving into MVVM pattern.
That said, I'd like to know if the reason it doesn't work is a matter of limitation of XAML and WPF engine, or more easily an error on my approach.

Comment: Ok, but if to say about my experience, I've never used ObjectDataProvider because it is better for me to work with collections in models than in views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue on my approach.
Simply, I didn't get that the ComboBox.SelectedValue type depends on how I populate the combobox (wich I did in code behind).
Simply modifying the ObjectDataProvider definition in the following way, resolved the problem:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="HorseDataProvider"
             ObjectType="{x:Type local:HorseDataProvider}"
             MethodName="GetCorse" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>                
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <x:Static Member="system:String.Empty" />                 
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

This way the ComboBox.SelectedItem is bound to an Int32 method parameter.